# How to change the shortcut to adjust brightness?

Tags: shortcut-keys, brightness

I want to make my own shortcut to increase or decrease brightness.

I don't like the default shortcut of my HP laptop (<kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> to decrease and <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd> to increase).

Is it possible?

Comment: related http://askubuntu.com/questions/240857/what-commands-will-change-my-screens-brightness

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes I did it again! Thanks to myself!

1) [Install XDoTool](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xdotool) and [Compiz](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager)

```
sudo aptitude install xdotool compizconfig-settings-manager
```

2) Open CompizConfig Settings Manager

```
ccsm
```

3) Go to commands and add this lines:

```
xdotool key XF86MonBrightnessUp  

xdotool key XF86MonBrightnessDown
```

[image]

I hope I enjoy ;-)

Comment: This doesn't seem to exist in version `0.9.8.5`.

Comment: I have a Logitech keyboard MK700 and I am trying assign a shortcut for brightness.The Logitech keyboard is secondary and connected to a laptop wirelessly.I followed your instruction but they don't work at all.I restarted my system but still nothing.

Comment: You shouldn't need to restart for this to work. Did you remember to go to the "Key Bindings" tab and assign some shortcut to the command? Does the command work if you run it from a terminal?