# Is there a way to set a hotkey to change screen brightness?

Tags: 12.04, shortcut-keys, brightness

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change the shortcut to adjust brightness?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34979/how-to-change-the-shortcut-to-adjust-brightness)

The brightness keys on my laptop are not recognized by Ubuntu, which is a common problem for a variety of laptops, is there a way to set an arbitrary key shortcut to change brightness in Ubuntu 12.04? I looked in the Keyboard settings app under the shortcut tab, and I couldn't find one.

I am able to set brightness in the Brightness and Lock settings app, but it would be much more convenient if I could just assign a key shortcut, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a generic way to set arbitrary brightness up/down keys on Ubuntu 12.04 using the Keyboard settings app.

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

Open "Keyboard" settings app, go to Shortcut tab, click Custom Shortcut, then
the little + button to add a shortcut.

```
name: Brightness Up
command: xdotool key XF86MonBrightnessUp
```

and another:

```
name: Brightness Down
command: xdotool key XF86MonBrightnessDown
```

Click where it says "Disabled" and then hit the key-combo you want, I ended up using <kbd>F2</kbd> and <kbd>F3</kbd>.

In Ubuntu 16.04 use --clearmodifiers with the command, i.e.,

`name: Brightness Up 
command: xdotool key --clearmodifiers XF86MonBrightnessUp`

and

`name: Brightness Down 
command: xdotool key --clearmodifiers XF86MonBrightnessDown`

Comment: Doesn't appear to work for an Acer Aspire S3 on 12.04 with Fn+leftarrow/rightarrow.

Comment: Doesn't appear to work for an out-of-box Toshiba Satellite S55-A5375

Comment: Worked for me on a Toshiba Satellite L305 laptop (which is 7 years old)

Comment: In Ubuntu 15.10 this only works if adding --clearmodifiers. I.e. the commands are: "xdotool key --clearmodifiers XF86MonBrightnessUp" and "xdotool key --clearmodifiers XF86MonBrightnessDown"

Comment: Worked on Acer C720 Chromebook booting with OpenSUSE

Comment: It works perfectly well on Ubuntu 20.04. Anyway, I noticed that it lags a little bit. What can the reason for lagging be?