# Ubuntu refuses to boot with acpi_backlight=vendor

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 14.04, grub2, brightness

I bought a Dell Inspiron 14 5000 series and dual booted Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu GNOME 14.04. The brightness would not change, so I booted with kernel parameter `acpi_backlight=vendor` and it worked. I later had to return that specific unit because of a hardware defect for another one.

With the second (current) unit I installed just regular Ubuntu 14.04. I tried to use the kernel parameter `acpi_backlight=vendor` with it, but with `quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor` all it gave me was a black screen. I booted without quiet splash and it froze at allocating swap space.

Why is it refusing to boot?

I also tried adding `acpi_osi=Linux` to `acpi_backlight=vendor`. Still wouldn't boot. `acpi_osi=Linux` on its own does not have any effect.

Comment: What is the exact output on the screen at this point: "I booted without quiet splash and it froze at allocating swap space." ?

Comment: Is it relevant? It was a message about allocating ~ 8 gb of swap space (I have 8 gb of RAM) and then it froze

Comment: It's relevant because that's where it froze. This could be completely unrelated to your card and/or the swap. Chances are the clue is in whatever messages are on the screen. Add a verbose paramater so you can see everything that's happening at boot and then post a picture here and maybe someone will figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me once and I found an answer here:
[How do I adjust the screen brightness on an Acer Aspire One D270?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195011/how-do-i-adjust-the-screen-brightness-on-an-acer-aspire-one-d270)

It was about brightness issues and this fixed it for me:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux i915.i915_enable_rc6=1"
```

There are a lot of other parameters suggested as well.

Comment: Did not do anything.