# Screen Brightness on Acer AspireV: bar appears, brightness doesn't change

Tags: 12.04, laptop, screen, brightness, acer

Using 12.04 on an Acer Aspire V5-561-9410.  When I use the function keys to modify screen brightness (or use any solutions I've found here to this problem like the one found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/174770/is-there-a-way-to-set-a-hotkey-to-change-screen-brightness) or [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75219/screen-brightness-not-adjustable-for-acer-aspire-s3)), I see the brightness bar appear and change in the top right of my screen, but my actual screen brightness doesn't change.  Does anyone know of a fix for this?  I'm assuming it's a related issue, but I also don't see any change in screen brightness when going from running on AC power to running on battery.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most modest approach, but it works for my Ubuntu 12.04 Acer.

You will need to run this command as super user (su).

```
$ sudo su
# echo 200 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

This will change your brightness (on a scale of 0-1000). Be careful you don't put in 0 or your screen will turn off!

If this process works for your machine, it's not too difficult to write a short script that macros the command to your keyboards shortcut keys.