# Brightness control Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, brightness, asus

I recently switched from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 16.04 and have been doing okay so far. One of my problems, though, is that I have to go to system settings to switch the brightness of the screen. I have looked up many solutions, but I'm not sure which one is the simplest, hopefully someone can teach me a way to have a keyboard shortcut for this.

I have an Asus Zenbook UX303L (not sure if matters).

I have tried editing in the `grub GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to:

- `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="`
- `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash quiet acpi_osi='!Windows 2012'"`
- `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux"`

To no success, this actually makes me unable to change the brightness through system settings.

Comment: `acpi_osi=` boot parameter should enable Fn+F5 and F6 keys. Also you may need to et brightness control to Intel. There is lots of guides.

Comment: After you added `acpi_osi=` did you update grub?

Comment: Yes I did, every time I changed it i would update the grub and restart the computer

Answer (score 0):

This is unrelated to your GRUB issue, but it does solve your having to go into the settings to change the brightness problem.

I did a Google search related to your topic and found this page:

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/04/brightness-control-ubuntu

After installing this and testing it myself, less the keyboard feature, I can say it does work, minus a few quirks. (Scroll wheeling the icon messed the program up for me)

If you do not know how to install PPAs, you do it by opening up Settings, hitting Software & Updates, clicking Other Software, and clicking Add.

To install packages, you can either use apt-get or my preferred method, Synaptic.

Comment: Thanks! I also looked at that solution but I would like to make it work as intended. In the meantime I'm using this solution http://askubuntu.com/questions/174770/is-there-a-way-to-set-a-hotkey-to-change-screen-brightness

Comment: I can't use the fn+F5/F6 combo but it works (trying to get use to the askubuntu format)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with the brightness on my Gateway laptop (with integrated Intel graphics) and found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/769006/brightness-key-not-working-ubuntu-16-04-lts#).

Instead of modifying the `acpi_osi=` value, what worked for me was to add `acpi_backlight=vendor` to the end of that command in `"/etc/default/grub"`

I had previously added `acpi_osi=Linux` to that line to solve the same issue in a previous version of Ubuntu (before upgrading to 16.04 LTS), so my full (working) line reads like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

Of course, after editing that file, it's necessary to save the changes, then run `sudo update-grub` and restart.

After doing this, my keyboard shortcuts for brightness are working again.