# What commands will change my screen's brightness?

Tags: shortcut-keys, brightness, command-line

I'm trying to re-keybind some of my function keys as I never use them for multimedia purposes, however I'm not sure as to what command I'd need to put it to increase/reduce the brightness, I'm talking about the command asked for below once you try creating your own custom shortcut:

> > [image]

Is there a standard terminal `command` to reduce the brightness (and increase it)? Ideally by a set percentage (10% for example), or alternatively a set value decrease which I'd need to find out from my hardware.

As extra information I can already control my brightness by pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> to decrease and increase respectively but I'd like to be able to simply press <kbd>F7</kbd> and <kbd>F8</kbd> as its simpler. I'm also using Ubuntu 12.04 with Unity if it changes anything.

As requested by iSeth below, output of `xmodmap -pke | less` (keycodes 66-77 are the Function buttons, apologies for large wall of terminal output):

```
keycode   8 =
keycode   9 = Escape NoSymbol Escape
keycode  10 = 1 exclam 1 exclam onesuperior exclamdown onesuperior
keycode  11 = 2 quotedbl 2 quotedbl twosuperior oneeighth twosuperior
keycode  12 = 3 sterling 3 sterling threesuperior sterling threesuperior
keycode  13 = 4 dollar 4 dollar EuroSign onequarter EuroSign
keycode  14 = 5 percent 5 percent onehalf threeeighths onehalf
keycode  15 = 6 asciicircum 6 asciicircum threequarters fiveeighths threequarters
keycode  16 = 7 ampersand 7 ampersand braceleft seveneighths braceleft
keycode  17 = 8 asterisk 8 asterisk bracketleft trademark bracketleft
keycode  18 = 9 parenleft 9 parenleft bracketright plusminus bracketright
keycode  19 = 0 parenright 0 parenright braceright degree braceright
keycode  20 = minus underscore minus underscore backslash questiondown backslash
keycode  21 = equal plus equal plus dead_cedilla dead_ogonek dead_cedilla
keycode  22 = BackSpace BackSpace BackSpace BackSpace
keycode  23 = Tab ISO_Left_Tab Tab ISO_Left_Tab
keycode  24 = q Q q Q at Greek_OMEGA at
keycode  25 = w W w W lstroke Lstroke lstroke
keycode  26 = e E e E e E e
keycode  27 = r R r R paragraph registered paragraph
keycode  28 = t T t T tslash Tslash tslash
keycode  29 = y Y y Y leftarrow yen leftarrow
keycode  30 = u U u U downarrow uparrow downarrow
keycode  31 = i I i I rightarrow idotless rightarrow
keycode  32 = o O o O oslash Oslash oslash
keycode  33 = p P p P thorn THORN thorn
keycode  34 = bracketleft braceleft bracketleft braceleft dead_diaeresis dead_abovering dead_diaeresis
keycode  35 = bracketright braceright bracketright braceright dead_tilde dead_macron dead_tilde
keycode  36 = Return NoSymbol Return
keycode  37 = Control_L NoSymbol Control_L
keycode  38 = a A a A ae AE ae
keycode  39 = s S s S ssharp section ssharp
keycode  40 = d D d D eth ETH eth
keycode  41 = f F f F dstroke ordfeminine dstroke
keycode  42 = g G g G eng ENG eng
keycode  43 = h H h H hstroke Hstroke hstroke
keycode  44 = j J j J dead_hook dead_horn dead_hook
keycode  45 = k K k K kra ampersand kra
keycode  46 = l L l L lstroke Lstroke lstroke
keycode  47 = semicolon colon semicolon colon dead_acute dead_doubleacute dead_acute
keycode  48 = apostrophe at apostrophe at dead_circumflex dead_caron dead_circumflex
keycode  49 = grave notsign grave notsign bar bar bar
keycode  50 = Shift_L NoSymbol Shift_L
keycode  51 = numbersign asciitilde numbersign asciitilde dead_grave dead_brevedead_grave
keycode  52 = z Z z Z guillemotleft less guillemotleft
keycode  53 = x X x X guillemotright greater guillemotright
keycode  54 = c C c C cent copyright cent
keycode  55 = v V v V leftdoublequotemark leftsinglequotemark leftdoublequotemark
keycode  56 = b B b B rightdoublequotemark rightsinglequotemark rightdoublequotemark
keycode  57 = n N n N n N n
keycode  58 = m M m M mu masculine mu
keycode  59 = comma less comma less horizconnector multiply horizconnector
keycode  60 = period greater period greater periodcentered division periodcentered
keycode  61 = slash question slash question dead_belowdot dead_abovedot dead_belowdot
keycode  62 = Shift_R NoSymbol Shift_R
keycode  63 = KP_Multiply KP_Multiply KP_Multiply KP_Multiply KP_Multiply KP_Multiply XF86ClearGrab
keycode  64 = Alt_L Meta_L Alt_L Meta_L
keycode  65 = space NoSymbol space
keycode  66 = Caps_Lock NoSymbol Caps_Lock
keycode  67 = F1 F1 F1 F1 F1 F1 XF86Switch_VT_1
keycode  68 = F2 F2 F2 F2 F2 F2 XF86Switch_VT_2
keycode  69 = F3 F3 F3 F3 F3 F3 XF86Switch_VT_3
keycode  70 = F4 F4 F4 F4 F4 F4 XF86Switch_VT_4
keycode  71 = F5 F5 F5 F5 F5 F5 XF86Switch_VT_5
keycode  72 = F6 F6 F6 F6 F6 F6 XF86Switch_VT_6
keycode  73 = F7 F7 F7 F7 F7 F7 XF86Switch_VT_7
keycode  74 = F8 F8 F8 F8 F8 F8 XF86Switch_VT_8
keycode  75 = F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 XF86Switch_VT_9
keycode  76 = F10 F10 F10 F10 F10 F10 XF86Switch_VT_10
keycode  77 = Num_Lock NoSymbol Num_Lock
keycode  78 = Scroll_Lock NoSymbol Scroll_Lock
keycode  79 = KP_Home KP_7 KP_Home KP_7
keycode  80 = KP_Up KP_8 KP_Up KP_8
keycode  81 = KP_Prior KP_9 KP_Prior KP_9
keycode  82 = KP_Subtract KP_Subtract KP_Subtract KP_Subtract KP_Subtract KP_Subtract XF86Prev_VMode
keycode  83 = KP_Left KP_4 KP_Left KP_4
keycode  84 = KP_Begin KP_5 KP_Begin KP_5
keycode  85 = KP_Right KP_6 KP_Right KP_6
keycode  86 = KP_Add KP_Add KP_Add KP_Add KP_Add KP_Add XF86Next_VMode
keycode  87 = KP_End KP_1 KP_End KP_1
keycode  88 = KP_Down KP_2 KP_Down KP_2
keycode  89 = KP_Next KP_3 KP_Next KP_3
keycode  90 = KP_Insert KP_0 KP_Insert KP_0
keycode  91 = KP_Delete KP_Decimal KP_Delete KP_Decimal
keycode  92 = ISO_Level3_Shift NoSymbol ISO_Level3_Shift
keycode  93 =
keycode  94 = backslash bar backslash bar bar brokenbar bar
keycode  95 = F11 F11 F11 F11 F11 F11 XF86Switch_VT_11
keycode  96 = F12 F12 F12 F12 F12 F12 XF86Switch_VT_12
keycode  97 =
keycode  98 = Katakana NoSymbol Katakana
keycode  99 = Hiragana NoSymbol Hiragana
keycode 100 = Henkan_Mode NoSymbol Henkan_Mode
keycode 101 = Hiragana_Katakana NoSymbol Hiragana_Katakana
keycode 102 = Muhenkan NoSymbol Muhenkan
keycode 103 =
keycode 104 = KP_Enter NoSymbol KP_Enter
keycode 105 = Control_R NoSymbol Control_R
keycode 106 = KP_Divide KP_Divide KP_Divide KP_Divide KP_Divide KP_Divide XF86Ungrab
keycode 107 = Print Sys_Req Print Sys_Req
keycode 108 = ISO_Level3_Shift Multi_key ISO_Level3_Shift Multi_key
keycode 109 = Linefeed NoSymbol Linefeed
keycode 110 = Home NoSymbol Home
keycode 111 = Up NoSymbol Up
keycode 112 = Prior NoSymbol Prior
keycode 113 = Left NoSymbol Left
keycode 114 = Right NoSymbol Right
keycode 115 = End NoSymbol End
keycode 116 = Down NoSymbol Down
keycode 117 = Next NoSymbol Next
keycode 118 = Insert NoSymbol Insert
keycode 119 = Delete NoSymbol Delete
keycode 120 =
keycode 121 = XF86AudioMute NoSymbol XF86AudioMute
keycode 122 = XF86AudioLowerVolume NoSymbol XF86AudioLowerVolume
keycode 123 = XF86AudioRaiseVolume NoSymbol XF86AudioRaiseVolume
keycode 124 = XF86PowerOff NoSymbol XF86PowerOff
keycode 125 = KP_Equal NoSymbol KP_Equal
keycode 126 = plusminus NoSymbol plusminus
keycode 127 = Pause Break Pause Break
keycode 128 = XF86LaunchA NoSymbol XF86LaunchA
keycode 129 = KP_Decimal KP_Decimal KP_Decimal KP_Decimal
keycode 130 = Hangul NoSymbol Hangul
keycode 131 = Hangul_Hanja NoSymbol Hangul_Hanja
keycode 132 =
keycode 133 = Super_L NoSymbol Super_L
keycode 134 = Super_R NoSymbol Super_R
keycode 135 = Menu NoSymbol Menu
keycode 136 = Cancel NoSymbol Cancel
keycode 137 = Redo NoSymbol Redo
keycode 138 = SunProps NoSymbol SunProps
keycode 139 = Undo NoSymbol Undo
keycode 140 = SunFront NoSymbol SunFront
keycode 141 = XF86Copy NoSymbol XF86Copy
keycode 142 = SunOpen NoSymbol SunOpen
keycode 143 = XF86Paste NoSymbol XF86Paste
keycode 144 = Find NoSymbol Find
keycode 145 = XF86Cut NoSymbol XF86Cut
keycode 146 = Help NoSymbol Help
keycode 147 = XF86MenuKB NoSymbol XF86MenuKB
keycode 148 = XF86Calculator NoSymbol XF86Calculator
keycode 149 =
keycode 150 = XF86Sleep NoSymbol XF86Sleep
keycode 151 = XF86WakeUp NoSymbol XF86WakeUp
keycode 152 = XF86Explorer NoSymbol XF86Explorer
keycode 153 = XF86Send NoSymbol XF86Send
keycode 154 =
keycode 155 = XF86Xfer NoSymbol XF86Xfer
keycode 156 = XF86Launch1 NoSymbol XF86Launch1
keycode 157 = XF86Launch2 NoSymbol XF86Launch2
keycode 158 = XF86WWW NoSymbol XF86WWW
keycode 159 = XF86DOS NoSymbol XF86DOS
keycode 160 = XF86ScreenSaver NoSymbol XF86ScreenSaver
keycode 161 =
keycode 162 = XF86RotateWindows NoSymbol XF86RotateWindows
keycode 163 = XF86Mail NoSymbol XF86Mail
keycode 164 = XF86Favorites NoSymbol XF86Favorites
keycode 165 = XF86MyComputer NoSymbol XF86MyComputer
keycode 166 = XF86Back NoSymbol XF86Back
keycode 167 = XF86Forward NoSymbol XF86Forward
keycode 168 =
keycode 169 = XF86Eject NoSymbol XF86Eject
keycode 170 = XF86Eject XF86Eject XF86Eject XF86Eject
keycode 171 = XF86AudioNext NoSymbol XF86AudioNext
keycode 172 = XF86AudioPlay XF86AudioPause XF86AudioPlay XF86AudioPause
keycode 173 = XF86AudioPrev NoSymbol XF86AudioPrev
keycode 174 = XF86AudioStop XF86Eject XF86AudioStop XF86Eject
keycode 175 = XF86AudioRecord NoSymbol XF86AudioRecord
keycode 176 = XF86AudioRewind NoSymbol XF86AudioRewind
keycode 177 = XF86Phone NoSymbol XF86Phone
keycode 178 =
keycode 179 = XF86Tools NoSymbol XF86Tools
keycode 180 = XF86HomePage NoSymbol XF86HomePage
keycode 181 = XF86Reload NoSymbol XF86Reload
keycode 182 = XF86Close NoSymbol XF86Close
keycode 183 =
keycode 184 =
keycode 185 = XF86ScrollUp NoSymbol XF86ScrollUp
keycode 186 = XF86ScrollDown NoSymbol XF86ScrollDown
keycode 187 = parenleft NoSymbol parenleft
keycode 188 = parenright NoSymbol parenright
keycode 189 = XF86New NoSymbol XF86New
keycode 190 = Redo NoSymbol Redo
keycode 191 = XF86Tools NoSymbol XF86Tools
keycode 192 = XF86Launch5 NoSymbol XF86Launch5
keycode 193 = XF86Launch6 NoSymbol XF86Launch6
keycode 194 = XF86Launch7 NoSymbol XF86Launch7
keycode 195 = XF86Launch8 NoSymbol XF86Launch8
keycode 196 = XF86Launch9 NoSymbol XF86Launch9
keycode 197 =
keycode 198 =
keycode 199 = XF86TouchpadToggle NoSymbol XF86TouchpadToggle
keycode 200 = XF86TouchpadOn NoSymbol XF86TouchpadOn
keycode 201 = XF86TouchpadOff NoSymbol XF86TouchpadOff
keycode 202 =
keycode 203 = Mode_switch NoSymbol Mode_switch
keycode 204 = NoSymbol Alt_L NoSymbol Alt_L
keycode 205 = NoSymbol Meta_L NoSymbol Meta_L
keycode 206 = NoSymbol Super_L NoSymbol Super_L
keycode 207 = NoSymbol Hyper_L NoSymbol Hyper_L
keycode 208 = XF86AudioPlay NoSymbol XF86AudioPlay
keycode 209 = XF86AudioPause NoSymbol XF86AudioPause
keycode 210 = XF86Launch3 NoSymbol XF86Launch3
keycode 211 = XF86Launch4 NoSymbol XF86Launch4
keycode 212 = XF86LaunchB NoSymbol XF86LaunchB
keycode 213 = XF86Suspend NoSymbol XF86Suspend
keycode 214 = XF86Close NoSymbol XF86Close
keycode 215 = XF86AudioPlay NoSymbol XF86AudioPlay
keycode 216 = XF86AudioForward NoSymbol XF86AudioForward
keycode 217 =
keycode 218 = Print NoSymbol Print
keycode 219 =
keycode 220 = XF86WebCam NoSymbol XF86WebCam
keycode 221 =
keycode 222 =
keycode 223 = XF86Mail NoSymbol XF86Mail
keycode 224 = XF86Messenger NoSymbol XF86Messenger
keycode 225 = XF86Search NoSymbol XF86Search
keycode 226 = XF86Go NoSymbol XF86Go
keycode 227 = XF86Finance NoSymbol XF86Finance
keycode 228 = XF86Game NoSymbol XF86Game
keycode 229 = XF86Shop NoSymbol XF86Shop
keycode 230 =
keycode 231 = Cancel NoSymbol Cancel
keycode 232 = XF86MonBrightnessDown NoSymbol XF86MonBrightnessDown
keycode 233 = XF86MonBrightnessUp NoSymbol XF86MonBrightnessUp
keycode 234 = XF86AudioMedia NoSymbol XF86AudioMedia
keycode 235 = XF86Display NoSymbol XF86Display
keycode 236 = XF86KbdLightOnOff NoSymbol XF86KbdLightOnOff
keycode 237 = XF86KbdBrightnessDown NoSymbol XF86KbdBrightnessDown
keycode 238 = XF86KbdBrightnessUp NoSymbol XF86KbdBrightnessUp
keycode 239 = XF86Send NoSymbol XF86Send
keycode 240 = XF86Reply NoSymbol XF86Reply
keycode 241 = XF86MailForward NoSymbol XF86MailForward
keycode 242 = XF86Save NoSymbol XF86Save
keycode 243 = XF86Documents NoSymbol XF86Documents
keycode 244 = XF86Battery NoSymbol XF86Battery
keycode 245 = XF86Bluetooth NoSymbol XF86Bluetooth
keycode 246 = XF86WLAN NoSymbol XF86WLAN
keycode 247 =
keycode 248 =
keycode 249 =
keycode 250 =
keycode 251 =
keycode 252 =
keycode 253 =
keycode 254 =
keycode 255 =
```

*Edit: Stumbled across a relevant question and thought that one of the solutions of ["How can I change brightness through terminal?"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56155/how-can-i-change-brightness-through-terminal) could work with my laptop but none did, I'm running a HP Pavilion DV6000 and I forgot to mention I'd prefer being able to run a command without needing root access if possible.*

As for using **xdotool** it changes the stated brightness here:

[image]

But the screen remains at the current brightness so doesn't affect the hardware related to brightness in my case.

Comment: Can you add the output of `xmodmap -pke | less` to your question please :)

Comment: I don't mean to bother you, but have you tried my solution yet?

Comment: @Seth feel free to bother me, yes I've just tried it, lets talk in chat ;)

Comment: take a look at `/etc/acpi/` too

Comment: If you still interested let's talk.

Answer (score 13):

If `xbacklight` fails and keyboard shortcuts(eg:<kbd>fn+F4</kbd>) changes the brightness following method should work.

**dbus way**

```
dbus-send --session --print-reply --dest="org.gnome.SettingsDaemon" /org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Power org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.Screen.SetPercentage uint32:`percentage`
```

For Example: Set brightness to 30%

```
dbus-send --session --print-reply --dest="org.gnome.SettingsDaemon" /org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Power org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.Screen.SetPercentage uint32:30
```

If it says as follows your OS may too old. Then use `xdotool`

> Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "SetPercentage" with signature "u" on interface "org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.Screen" doesn't exist

**xdotool**
BrightnessUp  : `xdotool key XF86MonBrightnessUp`
BrightnessDown: `xdotool key XF86MonBrightnessDown`

Comment: I really want to learn dbus stuff, know of any cool links to save me from the google firehose?

Comment: Why not ask as *dbus-where-to-get-started* :   http://askubuntu.com/questions/276392/dbus-where-to-get-started

Comment: @oyibo: What abt dbus

Comment: @Usingtotti I get the following output for **dbus** which makes me think it doesn't work in my case: `method return sender=:1.4 -> dest=:1.153 reply_serial=2 uint32 30` otherwise the **xdotool** method makes the brightness levels stated in the top-right bar in unity change but the screen stays at the same brightness :(

Comment: Both dbus and xdotool methods are working fine here with 12.10.

Answer (score 9):

You can probably use the `xbacklight` tool, which doesn't require root permissions:

```
xbacklight +30%        # increases brightness by 30 percent
xbacklight -30%        # decreases brightness by 30 percent
```

See `man xbacklight` for all the available options. Of course, if you don't have `xbacklight` you need to install it:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install xbacklight
```

Comment: `xbacklight` doesn't do anything for me.  It might work for the OP though.

Comment: Not working for me either unforunately, thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 7):

You have to do it with superuser privileges, on my system it refused to grant access for `sudo`er so I did it by first changing the user to `su` by running `sudo su` and then performed those commands.

To find out the maximum level of brightness for screen run:

```
cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/max_brightness
```

That should print `7` or whatever in your case, this is the maximum level you can increase the brightness upto, now to change the brightness run

```
echo "5" >> /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

basically changing `"5"` from `1-7` will increase or decrease the brightness.

**Note**: For those who get No Such File or directory executing the above commands will have replace acpi_video0 with other options available. To get a list of all available try this command:

```
ls /sys/class/backlight/
```

and then try the echo and cat commands with whatever you get by ls

Comment: The first line didn't work I get: `cat: /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/max_brightness: No such file or directory` I've tried both with regular `sudo` and `sudo su` privileges.

Comment: can you check for exact video device in `/sys/class/backlight/` ? either from nautilus or just double tab at terminal ?

Comment: `intel_backlight` also whats strange is in there there's the max brightness file and it says 1...

Comment: did you try echoing the values for brightness in `brightness` file regardless ?

Comment: Like this: `echo /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/max_brightness`? Yes nothing comes up, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: No no, that is not what I mean, do this instead `echo "5" >> /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`

Comment: I got `bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument`

Comment: Apparently your screen is set to a fixed brightness level, i don't think you can do it the command line way.

Comment: Try `sudo nano /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`, then change the value, press Ctrl + O to save and press Ctrl + X to exit. As soon as you save this file, the brightness changes.

Answer (score 3):

**TEST IT**

Create a file in your home directory called `.xmodmap`:  `touch .xmodmap`

Then open the file to edit the contents: `gedit .xmodmap`

Add these lines:

```
!Make the F7 key brightness down
keycode  73 = XF86MonBrightnessDown NoSymbol XF86MonBrightnessDown
!Make the F8 key brightness up  
keycode  74 = XF86MonBrightnessUp NoSymbol XF86MonBrightnessUp
```

Save the file then run `xmodmap .xmodmap`.  If the keys now do what you want, continue.  If not delete the `.xmodmap` file from your home.

**CONTINUED**

Open startup applications from the dash.  Click "Add".  Put `xmodmap .xmodmap` in the command field.  The other fields are optional, you can leave them blank.  Click "Add" again.  This makes Xmodmap run at startup.

[image]

Comment: @Oyibo The first thing to try is (after removing any changes you made earlier) running: `xmodmap -e "keycode  73 = XF86MonBrightnessDown NoSymbol XF86MonBrightnessDown"` and seeing if that changes anything.

Comment: What did you use to take that screenshot?

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs I used a program called [shutter](http://shutter-project.org/).

Answer (score 3):

There is a brightness indicator that you can dowload http://codevanrohde.nl/wordpress/?p=128. It is the only solution I have found that works on my laptop. With it you can set up hot keys to control brightness, use your mousewheel or select from a drop down list in the indicator. I have replaced 'Fn' with 'Win+Alt' which is very similar for my hands and now I can also use it with an external keyboard!

To add PPA and install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:indicator-brightness/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install indicator-brightness
```

Hot keys should be assigned to:

```
/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/indicator-brightness/indicator-brightness-adjust --up
```

and

```
/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/indicator-brightness/indicator-brightness-adjust --down
```