# D-Bus : Where to get started?

Tags: dbus

Many every day actions in Ubuntu can be done easily from terminal using `dbus`. The main advantage is it can be done exactly the GUI does, using a one liner, such as *change brightness*, *copy file*, etc.

- For example, to decrease brightness standard terminal method is:

  ```
  xbacklight +30%      #-30%
  ```

  While dbus method (I break line for better readability):

  ```
  dbus-send --session --print-reply --dest="org.gnome.SettingsDaemon" \
      /org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Power \
      org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.Screen.SetPercentage uint32:30
  ```
- To copy file

  ```
  cp ./a/source ./b/destination
  ```

  and:

  ```
  qdbus org.gnome.Nautilus /org/gnome/Nautilus \
      org.gnome.Nautilus.FileOperations.CopyFile \
      "file:///source/directory" "*" \
      "file:///destination/directory" ""
  ```

In `qdbus` graphical indicators are displayed with speed and canel button.

So the `dbus` is something interesting and I really want to learn D-Bus stuff. Please guide my by providing some e-books, links, etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is quite a concise list of documentations available from:

- [Freedesktop.org DBus Documentations](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus#Documentation)

to learn basics and procedures when it comes to use dbus in our applications.

Another good resource for finding out how implemented dbus properties work is  experimenting with dbus calls using the rather nice tool [d-feet](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/d-feet) [image: Install d-feet]. With this you can inspect or call available dbus properties from the system or the session bus:

[image]