# How can I check for available dbus services ?

Tags: 12.04, dbus

Dose any one knows how to check on all available dbus in ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: this may help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/276392/dbus-where-to-get-started

Answer (score 2):

[D-feet](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/d-feet/) is a great tool for that.  You can view all the properties and methods in a nice GUI and even call the methods.